# How to create a column with the value based on the condition of another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying this

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(range(0, 10))
df[1] = df[0] % 2 == 0
df[2] = 1 if df[1] else 0
```

which gives me this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2233547/1119079756.py in ?()
      1 df = pd.DataFrame(range(0, 10))
      2 df[1] = df[0] % 2 == 0
----> 3 df[2] = 1 if df[1] else df[0]

~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in ?(self)
   1464     @final
   1465     def __nonzero__(self) -> NoReturn:
-> 1466         raise ValueError(
   1467             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1468             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1469         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting here.  Remember that `True` equals 1 and `False` equals 0, so your `df[1]` column already has the data you want.  At worst, you could do `df[2] = df[1].astype(int)`, but that seems silly.

Comment: The root of the problem is that the ternary operator (`x if y else z`) cannot be vectorized.  It's a pure Python expression, not involving pandas, and Python needs to have the center value be a simple boolean scalar.

Comment: The 1 and 0 are just examples I had a calculation in the real case, thanks for the comments

Comment: Well, the answer to your question depends very strongly on your data.  If you can't share what you're actually doing, we can't really help very much.

Comment: The question was marked as duplicated and the answer of the another question helped, no worries